# How to add string into list with repeating

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linked-list

I need to add the string item to the list. I got total about 25 item. It will cause me to add it to list repeatedly. Did anyone have any method that i can add to list without make a long of same code line?

```
 List<Raster> myRasterlist = new List<Raster>();


        // Get the file name
        string filepath = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\User Stuff\Map Data\RASTER\3069.tif";
        myRasterlist.Add(new Raster(filepath));

        filepath = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\User Stuff\Map Data\RASTER\3169.tif";
        myRasterlist.Add(new Raster(filepath));

        filepath = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\User Stuff\Map Data\RASTER\3265.tif";
        myRasterlist.Add(new Raster(filepath));

        filepath = @"C:\Users\User\Desktop\User Stuff\Map Data\RASTER\4357.tif";
        myRasterlist.Add(new Raster(filepath));
```

Comment: You could iterate over the files in the folder

Comment: Do they all live in a folder?

Comment: @MichaelRandall yes, they all in same folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming all the images live in the same directory, you could use [`Directory.EnumerateFiles`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.enumeratefiles?view=netframework-4.7.2) with a search mask, then project the results to a `List`

> Returns an enumerable collection of file names that meet specified
>   criteria.

```
var myRasterlist = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir, "*.tiff", SearchOption.TopDirectoryOnly)
                            .Select(file => new Raster(x));

// or

var myRasterlist = Directory.EnumerateFiles(dir)
                            .Select(file => new Raster(x));
```

Answer (score 1):

```
using System.IO;
...    

List<Raster> myRasterlist = new List<Raster>();

    foreach (string filepath in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderPath, "*.tif"))
    {
      myRasterlist.Add(new Raster(filepath));
    }
```

- I assumed every files are in same folder